# Highcharts combination of line chart and treemap

Tags: highcharts, combinations, treemap

I need to make a combination of draggable line chart and treemap.

See here: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/petiska/xwrhzo01/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: "treemap",
        data: [
        {id: "NS",name: 'NS_area', value:5},
        // ...
        }
    },{
        data: [[0, 100], [10,90.9], [20,81.8], [30,72.7]],
        type: 'line',
    }]
});
```

can I display x,y axis when using treemap? Do you have other idea how to combine both charts?

Comment: Try to include the relevant parts of the code in your question, as links might break in the future. I've addressed some of your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that might work for you is adding an additional axis and simply linking it to the original one.

For example, creating one "duplicate" x-axis and y-axis:

```
xAxis: [{
},{ 
    linkedTo: 0 
}],
yAxis: [{

}, { 
    linkedTo: 0 
}]
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/xwrhzo01/1/) of it in use. This makes the axis mimic the look you originally had.

If you want the line chart to be completely independent of the original axis, you could just do the following:

```
series: [{
    // ...
}, {
    data: [[0, 100], [10,90.9], [20,81.8], [30,72.7]],
    type: 'line',
    yAxis: 1,
    xAxis: 1,
    // ...
}],
xAxis: [{
},{ 
}],
yAxis: [{
}, { 
}],
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/xwrhzo01/2/) of it in use. This works as a completely separate axis.

Comment: This is a good start, also I'd like to move x-axis in middle. I can't see x-axis line, just numbers..
thanks
Petr

Comment: What do you mean in the middle? If you add a small `offset` to the axis it will move and more easily show the lines.

Comment: I have to apply zIndex on x-axis in order to see whole axis not just numbers (when x-axis is offset).

Comment: @PetrPerner I'm not entirely sure what problem you are having seeing the axis. The axis line? I see a missing axis-line for my y-axis, which can be fixed with `lineWidth: 1`. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xwrhzo01/15/)

Comment: Hello, now everything works as expected. However, can you help me with following: I need to restrict dynamically limits when dragging (e.g. dragMaxY). This doesn't work: chart.series[1].update({dragMinY: 80});

Comment: @PetrPerner I'm glad it works, however, when you encounter new unique problems it is probably better to ask them as new separate questions so that each problem has a very specific question that can be answered with a specific answer, instead of mashing several issues into one. I hope you understand what I mean.